# How to identify subsequent user actions based on prior visits

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want to identify the users who visited section a and then subsequently visited b. Given the following data structure. The table contains 300,000 rows and updates daily with approx. 8,000 rows:

```
**USERID**  **VISITID**     **SECTION**   Desired Solution--> **Conversion**
   1             1               a                                      0
   1             2               a                                      0
   2             1               b                                      0
   2             1               b                                      0
   2             1               b                                      0
   1             3               b                                      1
```

Ideally I want a new column that flags the visit to section b. For example on the third visit User 1 visited section b for the first time.  I was attempting to do this using a CASE WHEN statement but after many failed attempts I am not sure it is even possible with CASE WHEN and feel that I should take a different approach, I am just not sure what that approach should be.  I do also have a date column at my disposal.

Any suggestions on a new way to approach the problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Or I supposed help on how to accomplish the desired solution with CASE WHEN would be helpful to.

Comment: I noted in my question that I also have a date column at my disposal. (contains time info down to the second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlated sub-queries should be avoided at all cost when working with Redshift.  Keep in mind there are no indexes for Redshift so you'd have to rescan and restitch the column data back together *for each value* in the parent resulting in an O(n^2) operation (in this particular case going from 300 *thousand* values scanned to 90 *billion*).

The best approach when you are looking to span a series of rows is to use an analytic function.  There are a couple of options depending on how your data is structured but in the simplest case, you could use something like

```
select case 
       when section != lag(section) over (partition by userid order by visitid)
       then 1
       else 0
       end
 from ...
```

This assumes that your data for userid 2 increments the visitid as below.  If not, you could also order by your timestamp column

```
**USERID**  **VISITID**     **SECTION**   Desired Solution--> **Conversion**
   1             1               a                                      0
   1             2               a                                      0
   2             1               b                                      0
   2            *2*              b                                      0
   2            *3*              b                                      0
   1             3               b                                      1
```

Comment: This is much faster and I can run it over a larger data set without crashing my SQL workbench. Thanks!

Comment: It does but it appears to double count the metric I was looking for.

Comment: @camacnei That is because it doesn't do what you want. When you say "I want to identify the users who visited section a and then subsequently visited b" I doubt you EXCLUSIVELY want users who went to a and then b immediately after. For example, if a user goes to a, then to c, and then to b, the above query would not find that. It is only finding rows where a user went to a and then to b immediately after, not users who went to b and ANYTIME PREVIOUSLY went to a. It finds only users who JUST PREVIOUSLY went to a.

Comment: "This assumes that your data for userid 2 increments the visitid as below." Unless the sample data posted is incorrect, that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*, case when v.ts is null then 0 else 1 end as conversion
  from tbl t
  left join (select *
               from tbl x
              where section = 'b'
                and exists (select 1
                       from tbl y
                      where y.userid = x.userid
                        and y.section = 'a'
                        and y.ts < x.ts)) v
    on t.userid = v.userid
   and t.visitid = v.visitid
   and t.section = v.section
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b954/5/0

I added sample timestamp data as that field is necessary to determine whether a comes before b or after b.

To incorporate analytic functions you could use:

(I've also made it so that only the first occurrence of B (after an A) will get flagged with the 1)

```
select t.*,
       case
         when v.first_b_after_a is not null
         then 1
         else 0
        end as conversion
  from tbl t
  left join (select userid, min(ts) as first_b_after_a
               from (select t.*,
                            sum( case when t.section = 'a' then 1 end)
                                  over( partition by userid
                                        order by ts ) as a_sum
                       from tbl t) x
              where section = 'b'
                and a_sum is not null
              group by userid) v
    on t.userid = v.userid
   and t.ts = v.first_b_after_a
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fa88f/2/0

Comment: I've never seen CASE WHEN used like that bu then again I'm pretty new to SQL! Never would've thought to combine a join and case when like that. Thank! You! Trying it out now...